# Change selected navigation item text in action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am using ActionBarSherlock, and have an `ActionBar` with the navigation mode set `NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST`.  I would like to change the text of the currently selected navigation item that is showing within the `ActionBar`.  I have successfully been able to change the name of the item in the navigation drop down list.  This can be seen if one displays the drop down list by touching the navigation button in the `ActionBar`.  However, unless I switch to a different indexed item within the navigation drop down list, the text in the `ActionBar` will NOT change.I have tried a number of things, such as calling `setSelectedNavigationItem()` on the `ActionBar`, calling `invalidateOptionsMenu()`, etc. and nothing seems to work.

If anyone has any ideas about how to get the changed menu text to display, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't figure out how to do this; so, I eventually moved away from the idea and created a separate screen for managing the items in this list.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding custom layout.

Here is sample code

first define a layout for tabs

tab_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tabName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and then adding that layout as many times as your tabs.

```
//bar is your AcrionBar instance
LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
          final View tabView = factory.inflate(R.layout.tab_layout, null);
          TextView text = (TextView) tabView.findViewById(R.id.tabName);
          text.setText("tab1");

          bar.addTab(
              bar.newTab().setCustomView(tabView)

                      .setTabListener(tabListener));
          final View tabView1 = factory.inflate(R.layout.tab_layout, null);
          TextView text1 = (TextView) tabView1.findViewById(R.id.tabName);
          text1.setText("tab2");
          bar.addTab(
              bar.newTab().setCustomView(tabView1)
                      .setTabListener(tabListener));
          final View tabView2 = factory.inflate(R.layout.tab_layout, null);
          TextView text2 = (TextView) tabView2.findViewById(R.id.tabName);
          text2.setText("tab3");
          bar.addTab(
              bar.newTab().setCustomView(tabView2)
                      .setTabListener(tabListener));
```

then in TabListener you can set text color of selected navigation item text.

```
ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {


        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final View tabView = tab.getCustomView();
            TextView text = (TextView) tabView.findViewById(R.id.tabName);
            text.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black)); //There you have to put your inactive color
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            final View tabView = tab.getCustomView();
            TextView text = (TextView) tabView.findViewById(R.id.tabName);
            text.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.bgColor)); //There you have to put your active color


        }
      };
```